# PHP Iterate through arrays in object within an array

Tags: php, arrays, json, nested

i have a pretty weird json here. Im trying to iterate through every `subscription` object and get some data

Here is the json

```json
{
   "result":"success",
   "data":{
      "subscriptions":[
         {
            "name":"app_generator",
            "expirey":1628188363942,
            "hwids":3,
            "hwids_used":[
               "dc253a62ea65cd92c6cb26f15330cf4a8f9e5c3ecf7caae161a3f97de4c84515",
               "efede5757f512f9eae1d600302ca5c4e6a3cadb0658310c91c6da2ada68175f4"
            ]
         },
         {
            "name":"apple",
            "expirey":1625596518277,
            "hwids":2,
            "hwids_used":[
               "dc253a62ea65cd92c6cb26f15330cf4a8f9e5c3ecf7caae161a3f97de4c84515",
               "dc253a62ea65cd92c6cb26f15330cf4a8f9e5c3ecf7caae161a3f97de4c84515a"
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

The code i tried was:

```php
foreach($json['result']['data']['subscriptions'] as $a)
{
  //print_r($a);
  $expirey = $a['expirey']
}
```

Im just getting a lot of errors. Let me know what the correct approach would be. My goal is to mainly get the `name` & `expirey` data

Comment: What are the errors you are getting? and what does `$json` look like?

Comment: `data` is not under `result`.

Comment: I have added the json in my question(?) @KimHallberg

Comment: I get the response from a curl, and what i do is $json=json_decode($response, true)

Comment: @NigelRen What do you mean?

Comment: Most likely should be `$json['data']['subscriptions']`

Comment: Yes, like @NigelRen said, `$json['data']['subscriptions']`, here's a working [demo](https://3v4l.org/ro5S5).

Comment: Yes `data` is at the same level as `result`.  Use `print_r` or `var_dump` to see.